# Rails 3 migration error

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, migration

I am new to Ruby and Rails, and whenever I attempt to generate my database using rake db:migrate I get the following error:

**rake aborted!
You have already activated rake 0.9.3.beta.1, but your Gemfile requires rake 0.9.2. Consider using bundle exec.**

I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rails 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Consider using bundle exec.
```

There's your clue. Try this instead:

```
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Comment: extra reading related to this:  http://yehudakatz.com/2011/05/30/gem-versioning-and-bundler-doing-it-right/